# Periodically comparing the play count of two Last.FM users

Tags: haskell, logging, client

There is [some little program](https://gist.github.com/2188681) (using a Last.FM API wrapper) which gets the play count of 2 specific users every 5 minutes and appends the difference between these 2 numbers to log file.

Can you review that part of the code?
I think that using the `<-` operator so many times decreases the readability and simplicity of the code.

```
main = forever $ do
  diff <- user1 `subtractCounts` user2
  timestamp <- formatTime defaultTimeLocale dateFormat <$> getZonedTime
  let logMessage = printf "%s %d\n" timestamp diff :: String
  homeDir <- getHomeDirectory
  let logFilePath = homeDir </> logFile
  appendFile logFilePath logMessage
  threadDelay $ 10^6 * 60 * timeDelay -- in microseconds
    where
      subtractCounts = liftM2 ((-) `on` fromMaybe 0) `on` getPlayCount
      dateFormat = "[%s] %D %H:%M"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see why you say `<-` "decreases readability", but you could line them up if you think that helps (this style is typical of Haskell programmers)

```
main = forever $ do
  diff      <- user1 `subtractCounts` user2
  timestamp <- formatTime defaultTimeLocale dateFormat <$> getZonedTime
  homeDir   <- getHomeDirectory
  let logMessage  = printf "%s %d\n" timestamp diff
      logFilePath = homeDir </> logFile
  appendFile logFilePath logMessage
  threadDelay $ 10^6 * 60 * timeDelay -- in microseconds

subtractCounts = liftM2 ((-) `on` fromMaybe 0) `on` getPlayCount
dateFormat     = "[%s] %D %H:%M"
```

`<-` is a visual cue that the thing on the right might to perform an *effect* before producing a result and binding it to the name on the left.

Note that the type annotation on `logMessage` is unnecessary. Because it is used as the second argument to `appendFile` it will be inferred to be `String`.

I personally might make a few more refactorings, but they aren't really necessary:

```
logMessage :: String -> Integer -> String
logMessage  = printf "%s %d\n"

(f .: g) x y = f $ g x y

subtractCounts = liftM2 ((-) `on` fromMaybe 0) `on` getPlayCount


main = forever $ do
  homeDir <- getHomeDirectory
  let logFilePath = homeDir </> logFile
      logDiff     = appendFile logFilePath .: logMessage
  forever $ mainLoop logDiff

mainLoop logDiff = do
  diff      <- user1 `subtractCounts` user2
  timestamp <- formatTime defaultTimeLocale "[%s] %D %H:%M" <$> getZonedTime
  logDiff timestamp diff
  threadDelay $ 10^6 * 60 * timeDelay -- in microseconds
```

The type signature on `logMessage` is probably unnecessary, but imho it's a good idea to give it an explicit signature if you are using the result of `printf` as a function, rather than a `String` or `IO ()`.

Comment: Where is `.:` operator from?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention: `(f .: g) x y = f (g x y)`. It's not in the standard libraries, but is a common trick for writing pointfree code.

Comment: Actually you forgot about `threadDelay`.